# Not able to run Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0 even if installation is successful

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, cisco

I use Kali Linux and I am having a problem in running the `Cisco Packet Tracer v7.0`.

I have downloaded the PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz file from www.netacad.com/group/offerings/packet-tracer/. And then I extracted the tar.gz file by writing the command

```
tar -zxvf PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz
```

Then I got into the folder PacketTracer70 which got created automatically after extraction.

The folder contents were as follows:

[image: folder screenshot]
Then I ran the `./install` command in the terminal and I got the following:

```
root@hacker:~/PacketTracer70# ./install

Welcome to Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0 Installation

Read the following End User License Agreement "EULA" carefully. You must
accept the terms of this EULA to install and use Cisco Packet Tracer.
Press the Enter key to read the EULA.......
```

Then I accepted the terms and conditions as usual...

Then I was asked to install the package in `opt/pt` folder and I agreed as follows:
[image: installation successful message]

then I got to the folder `/opt/pt` and tried

```
root@hacker:~# cd /opt/pt root@hacker:/opt/pt# packettracer
```

But nothing happened after that. It just gave me the message "Starting Packet Tracer 7.0" and nothing happened.

```
root@hacker:~# cd /opt/pt
root@hacker:/opt/pt# packettracer
Starting Packet Tracer 7.0
root@hacker:/opt/pt#
```

I am trying this second time and getting the same problem. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add library path of PT7 to your Environment Variables as bellow:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/pt/lib
```

or

add following line to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/10-local.conf`:

```
/opt/pt/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `PacketTracer70/bin` and run `./PacketTracer`
2. If it returns about a missing or unshared libssl1.0.0 continue to #3
3. Install the appropriate version of lissl1.0.0 from [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libssl1.0.0)
4. Go to the downloaded package and run `dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u6_[YOURVERSION].deb .deb && apt-get install -f`
5. Now try the normal PacetTracer run script and it should work.
   I just got mine to work on my persistent USB.

Comment: Justin it appears you have two accounts; if you register [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/217446/justin-h) you'll be able to edit your own post.

Answer (score 0):

1. download and install [libssl1.0.0](https://packages.debian.org/en/jessie/libssl1.0.0) from Debian site,
2. install the .deb package normally.
   [image: install]

credits: tuto5min.blogspot.co.ke/2016/11/how-to-install-cisco-packet-tracer-7-in.html

//cant post more than two links

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an amd64, and I needed to install the following dependencies, to make packet tracer work:

```
/root/Downloads/libicu52_52.1-8+deb8u5_amd64.deb
/root/Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
/root/Downloads/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u6_amd64.deb
```

Attempting to run via: `/opt/pt/bin# ./PacketTracer7`, identified the missing dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the following, in here `/opt/pt/packettracer`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PTDIR/lib
```